# alsa config for startup

Tags: scripting, startup, alsa

I'm having a problem with my headphone.  A friendly person over at the #alsa irc channel came up with this to rectify:

```
sudo hda-verb /dev/snd/hwC0D0 0x15 SET_EAPD_BTLENABLE 2
```

However it has to be entered upon reboot.  It also asks for password.  Is there any way to automate this so it will run on startup?

Comment: On which distribution?

Answer (score 0):

Just put the command (without the `sudo`) into the executable script `/etc/rc.local` or `/etc/rc.d/rc.local`.

Comment: The traditional location is `/etc/rc.local`. Some systems don't support  `/etc/rc.d/rc.local`; which ones do?

Comment: Thanks! Most systems supports both; it appears I chose the wrong one as the more common one.